# subscription complete called before completion

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular 5 app I have a file upload component that takes a list of files dropped on the page and calls a file upload service for each.  I want to display a list of errors when all the files have been uploaded or rejected.

I have something like this:

```
Observable.from(files).subscribe(file=> {
      if (file.size > this.MAX_SIZE) {
        errors.push(`${file.name} is too large.`);
      } else if (this.validFileTypes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
        errors.push(`${file.name} is is not a valid image file.`);
      } else {

        this.uploading = true;
        this.uploadingFile = file.name;
        this.fileService.uploadFile(file)
          .subscribe((ev: any) => {
            if (ev.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
              // blah blah
            } else {
              this.uploading = false;
            }
          }, (err: any) => {
            errors.push(err);
          }
        );          
    });      
},
err => {},
() => {
  if (errors.length) {
    console.log('there were errors');
  }
});
```

The problem is the subscribe() complete call back gets called before anything else, before it even does the main callback.

I'm still pretty confused by this rx/js stuff so I'm sure Ive done something stupid again, but this is taking far too long to resolve.

Thanks for reading this far :)

**Update 1**

I tried the first suggestion from @Miller but am now getting an error:

**Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined**

My new method is this:

```
class DroppedFile {
  constructor(public droppedFile: any, public error: any) { }
}

public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
  const uploads: any[] = event.files.map(evf => new DroppedFile(evf, null));
  const subs = new Array<any>();

  uploads.forEach(upload => {
    if (upload.droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
      const fileEntry = upload.droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;

      fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
        if (file.size > this.MAX_SIZE) {
          upload.error = `${file.name} is too large.  Maximum file size is ${this.MAX_SIZE / 1024}KB.`;
        } else if (this.validFileTypes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
          upload.error = `${file.name} is is not a valid image file. You can only upload JPG, GIF & PNG files.`;
        }
      });
    }
  });

  uploads.filter(upload => upload.error == null).forEach(upload => {
    const fileUpload$ = this.fileService.uploadFile(upload.droppedFile, upload.droppedFile.relativePath)
      .catch((err: any, cort: Observable<any>) => {
        upload.error = err;
        return null;
      });

    subs.push(fileUpload$);
  });

  if (subs.length > 0) {
    Observable.forkJoin(...subs)  // BANG!  Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
      .subscribe((ev: any) => {
        this.uploading = true;
        if (ev.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.uploadingPercentage = Math.floor(ev.loaded * 100 / ev.total);
        } else {
          this.uploading = false;
        }
     }, (err: any) => {
        // errors.push(err);
      },
        () => {
          // display any errors
          this.getPage(0);
          this.showErrors(uploads);
        });
  } else {
    this.showErrors(uploads);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: a subscription within a subscription is something to try to avoid. You should find a way via operators, as suggested by @Miller, to eventually obtain only ONE Observable, the one you need to subscribe

Comment: Im gonna hack something with a setTimeout so I can make some progress.  Ive already spent a week on this.... doing my head in!

Comment: What version of RXJS are you using?

Comment: 5.5.7.  I just did an npm outdated and I think it's the latest.

Comment: Try to remove the `catch` operator, and handle errors within the `subscribe` method. Your `catch` returns a null, which may be the reason for your **BANG**

Comment: @Picci I think you've identified the problem - but catch is needed if you want to prevent an error from causing the whole forkJoin to fail... I believe what is needed is for the catch to return Observable.of(null);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your outer subscription is not waiting on the `uploadFile` calls.

To fix this, you could assemble the results of your fileUpload calls into an array. Then await them all completing by using [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) ...

```
const fileUploads: Observable<any>[] = [];
const errors = [];

files.forEach(file => {
  if (file.size > this.MAX_SIZE) {
    errors.push(`${file.name} is too large.`);
  } else if (this.validFileTypes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
    errors.push(`${file.name} is is not a valid image file.`);
  } else {
    const fileUpload$ = this.fileService.uploadFile(file)
      .catch((err: any) => {
        errors.push(err);
      });

    fileUploads.push(fileUpload$);  
  }
});

this.uploading = true;

Observable.forkJoin(...fileUploads).subscribe(
  () => {},
  err => {},
  () => {
    this.uploading = false;
    if (errors.length) {
      console.log('there were errors');
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It gave me another avenue to explore but ... another error to solve :)  See Update 1 above.  Cheers

Comment: I'm sure your answer is probably correct if I could get it to work :)  I just don't understand rx/js so I've given up for now and will use someone else's component that actually works - I just have to reshape my ui a little.  I must say that rx/js is counter-intuitive and far to computer-sciency for my liking, but that is probably my ignorance talking.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries - rxjs is definitely a high learning curve. I found that eventually it does click after some time